# Image button still working after being cleared from canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, button

I am using an image and making it into a Button object which when clicked is supposed to disappear and be inactive until it is called again. I click the button and the image is gone but the area that the image was over is still active as if the button is still there (i.e. if I click the area that the button was in, the code that was called by the button gets called again).

Here is the code for the button to be drawn from draw()

> ```
> ctx.beginPath();    
>     img=document.getElementById('btn');    
>     btn=new Button(img, (420-img.width/2), (280-img.height/2),  img.width, img.height);    
>     btn.draw(ctx);    
> ctx.closePath();
> ```

Here is draw from Button class

> ```
> Button.prototype.draw=function(ctx){    
>     ctx.beginPath();    
>          ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);    
>     ctx.closePath();     
> };
> ```

And here is the code that listens for and handles the button being clicked

> From HTML file

```
function mousePressed(inputEvent){        
    if(btn.clicked(inputEvent)){    
        start=Date.now();    
        score=0;    
        update();    
    }   
}
```

> From Button class

```
  Button.prototype.clicked=function(inputEvent){    
      var clickX=inputEvent.clientX;
      var clickY=inputEvent.clientY;
      return (clickX>=this.x && clickX<=(this.x+this.width) && clickY>=this.y && clickY<=this.y+this.height);
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

Given there aren't really objects on an HTML canvas like there are with HTML DOM elements such as divs, images, buttons etc the mousePressed event is probably being triggered by onClick of the canvas which means the if(btn.clicked(inputEvent)) code will still be running and checking if the click was inside the width and height of the button.

You could possibly add a property to the Button class to specify if its enabled or not and if not just skip the check if the user clicked on it.

```
function mousePressed(inputEvent){        
    // If button enabled and clicked then udpate
    if(btn.enabled && btn.clicked(inputEvent)){
        start=Date.now();    
        score=0;    
        update();    
    }   
}
```

In the button constructor set enabled=true then in the code which makes the button "disappear" set button.enabled to false. Actually you might already have a property to control if its drawn or not so could use the same to control if a click should be checked for?